# iOS - AccessoryView changes the size of custom separator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a grouped tableview and at first I wanted to remove the top and bottom separator. I looked around and found a solution that worked great form me. It was by adding a UIView to the bottom of the cell to act as the separator. Now it looks amazing. But the problem I faced is when I set the AccessoryView of the cell , because for some reason when I select the cell , my custom separator change its width . Here's a representation of the problem :

this is when not selected

[image: this is when not selected]

this is when selected :

[image]

Note that the custom separator already has constraint .

Any suggestions please ?

Edit:

Here's how I set the accessoryView :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "x"
            label.sizeToFit()
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium)
            if(cell.accessoryView == nil){
                cell.accessoryView = label
            }else{
                cell.accessoryView = nil
            }

        }
    }
```

that's it and everything else is just a simple tableview with rows and section , I also set the separator to none in storyboard.

Edit 2 :

This is the separator constraints :
[image]

Comment: Can you attach screenshot for constraint on separator?

Comment: @SaqibOmer I updated my question

Comment: @SaqibOmer I also tried to add a width constraint, but still same problem

Comment: You can implement this by using simple tableview with section wise data.

Comment: @Aashish1aug can you elaborate please?

Comment: Updated answer. It is a problem with constraints conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your trailing constraint. Instead of ContentView add trailing constraint to cell. Remove trailing constraint on separator view and add constraints as in image. 
[image]

Comment: do I bring the separator to front in cellForRowAtIndexPath method or in didSelectRow?

Comment: Yes. Change your delegate method as I have added code.

Comment: I just tried both of these methods but it didn't work :(

Comment: I only have SuperView and label as first item in constraint, I can't add constraints to the cell itself or the contentView : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlcSV.png

Comment: Anybody else having this issue again in iOS 13, even with this fix?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13+, I had to change the code to draw bottom border on the cell instead of the cell's contentView. I do it in `awakeFromNib` in the Cell class.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    addBorder(borderType: .bottom)
}


func addBorder(borderType: BorderType, width: CGFloat = 1.0, color: UIColor = .darkGray) {
        // figure out frame and resizing based on border type
        var autoresizingMask: UIView.AutoresizingMask
        var layerFrame: CGRect
        switch borderType {
        case .left:
            layerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: self.bounds.height)
            autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleHeight, .flexibleRightMargin ]
        case .right:
            layerFrame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.width - width, y: 0, width: width, height: self.bounds.height)
            autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleHeight, .flexibleLeftMargin ]
        case .top:
            layerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: width)
            autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin ]
        case .bottom:
            layerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height - width, width: self.bounds.width, height: width)
            autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin ]
        }

        // look for the existing border in subviews
        var newView: UIView?
        for eachSubview in self.subviews {
            if eachSubview.tag == borderType.rawValue {
                newView = eachSubview
                break
            }
        }

        // set properties on existing view, or create a new one
        if newView == nil {
            newView = UIView(frame: layerFrame)
            newView?.tag = borderType.rawValue
            self.addSubview(newView!)
        } else {
            newView?.frame = layerFrame
        }
        newView?.backgroundColor = color
        newView?.autoresizingMask = autoresizingMask
    }
```